# Return to activity with MapView, maintain previous overlays with points, add new points to those overlays

Tags: android, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay

*Please bear with my long description and read through. It's simple and I need your help :)*

LogIn activity gets map points from a server and launches Maps activity, a JSON string is passed to the Maps activity and the Maps activity reads the events and adds their points to the overlay.

I created a Service which runs in the background and when new points appear on the server they are to be added to the map once the user clicks on the notification. Once clicked, it launches the Maps activity to supposedly add the points to the existing ones (once again JSON string is passed by the Service to the Maps activity)

Problem here is that the Maps activity keeps on getting created (onCreate() runs everytime) and all previous points are erased from the map because of all overlays, mapview etc. are re-created as if it was the first time running it but the previous points are not added because they were passed by the LogIn screen which obviously doesn't run now.

How can I add points to the map without removing previous ones?

Thank you very much!